# VS2015 Typescript: enable JointJs grig in

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, grid, jointjs

i would like to know how enable grid of jointjs plugin by Typescript in VS2015.
I've tried to add properties drawGrid in IOptions interface in jointjs.d.ts and after i've setted the attributes in my .ts file:

```
 //Create Paper Option
 var viewopt = new Backbone.View();
 viewopt.el = $('#paper');
 viewopt.model = this.graph;
 viewopt.attributes = { gridSize: 50, drawGrid: true };
 //Create Paper
 this.paper = new joint.dia.Paper(viewopt);
```

In my .js output file i saw the property but the paper is always without grid.
Could you help me.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

`gridSize` is the paper option (not for the grid). Also `viewopt` doesn't need to be the Backbone View, a plain object is fine.

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('#paper'),
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    gridSize: 10,
    drawGrid: true,
    model: graph
});
```

Comment: it get 'drawGrid' does not exist in type 'PaperOptions'. in typescript

Comment: what is your joints version? this should be fixed in v1.1